# Cypress how to use 'cy.get' between two elements

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I want to search for an element and if I don't find it, find a second element:

```js
cy.get(@firstElement).or(@secondElement).click()
```

Is there some function I can use like `||` in conditions?

Answer (score 4):

The `,` for OR condition ***will not work*** if `firstElement` loads asynchronously.

Using the command

```
cy.get('firstElement, secondElement')      // no retry on firstElement
```

It goes straight to `secondElement` even if `firstElement` appears just 10ms later, or is animating.

So this technique skips the Cypress retry mechanism, which is why **Cypress does not mention it in the docs**.

---

One way I can see to make it work when `firstElement` is asynchronous is to catch the fail event.

**Note**
Cypress docs say to only use the fail event for debugging, but Cypress do use it in their own tests.

```js
Cypress.once('fail', () => {             // "once" means catch fail for next command only
  console.log('Clicking secondElement')
  Cypress.$('secondElement').trigger('click')
})

cy.get('firstElement', { log: false })   // retry for 'firstElement' but suppress log
  .click()                               // never executes this if 'firstElement' fails
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the comma `,` to do an OR condition if you are using css selectors. Something like:

```
cy.get('firstElement,secondElement').click()
```